# How to add array keys to the same array?

Tags: php, arrays, function

I have an array like this:

```php
[
    'one' => ['whatever'=>'something','whatever1'=>'something1'],
    'two' => ['whatever'=>'something','whatever1'=>'something1'],
    'three' => ['whatever'=>'something','whatever1'=>'something1'],
]
```

and now I wanna add the array keys to the same array with a specific key like below:

```php
[
    'one' => ['name'=>'one', 'whatever'=>'something','whatever1'=>'something1'],
    'two' => ['name'=>'two', 'whatever'=>'something','whatever1'=>'something1'],
    'three' => ['name'=>'three', 'whatever'=>'something','whatever1'=>'something1'],
]
```

I can handle this with `foreach()` but is there no function in PHP that can do this or in a shorter way?

Comment: If you have any influence on creating the array, it's better to start there.  If not then I think a `foreach` is the easiest method.

Comment: Looks like an XY Problem.  @No.The.Hi Why do you believe you need to add redundant data to the subarray?  The data is already available in the data payload.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is are lot of functions for array handling, if you are the starter then you have to do with `foreach`.

If you have an array named `$array` , then you can try this-

```
$array = array_map(function (array $arr, $arr_key) { return $arr + array('name' => $arr_key); }, $array, array_keys($array));
```

Comment: I still think `foreach` is a neater solution than using things like `array_map` in such a simple process. (although that is entirely IMHO)

Comment: This has slightly different output than expected in the question. The original keys are lost.